# Bootstrap Alert is not Working on my webpage on localhost

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Here is my alert code it is not working, I mean I cannot see anything on screen everything seems to be alright I think don't think there is javascript function that I am missing because its just a text

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <h4 class="alert-heading">Well done!</h4>
        <p>Aww yeah, you successfully read this important alert message. This example text is going to run a bit longer so that you can see how spacing within an alert works with this kind of content.</p>
        <hr>
        <p class="mb-0">Whenever you need to, be sure to use margin utilities to keep things nice and tidy.</p>
      </div>
```

These are the scripts that I am using:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post full HTML file please. According to [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) you should put that CSS link into the head tag. For [Bootstrap alert styling](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/alerts/) you don't need to include any JS files. It should work fine.